# Is it possible to obtain a backtrace inside a vDSO call?

Tags: multithreading, gdb, deadlock, system-calls, backtrace

I was trying to debug a deadlock issue in my code using gdb. When the program locked up, I attached to it with gdb to see what the threads were doing. For some reason, I cannot obtain backtraces for threads other than the current one:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb774dcb0 in ?? ()
#1  0x8420e178 in TableCollect 
#2  0x84200c12 in main
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 3 (Thread 0xb6becb40 (LWP 18937)):
#0  0xb774dcb0 in ?? ()
#1  0x000d6ee6 in ?? ()

Thread 2 (Thread 0xb1f5eb40 (LWP 18939)):
Python Exception <class 'gdb.MemoryError'> Cannot access memory at address 0x5:
#0  0xb774dcb0 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x5
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame
  3    Thread 0xb6becb40 (LWP 18937) "loader.elf" 0xb774dcb0 in ?? ()
  2    Thread 0xb1f5eb40 (LWP 18939) "Tuner" 0xb774dcb0 in ?? ()
* 1    Thread 0xb6bed700 (LWP 18936) "loader.elf" 0xb774dcb0 in ?? ()
(gdb) thread 2
[Switching to thread 2 (Thread 0xb1f5eb40 (LWP 18939))]
#0  0xb774dcb0 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
Python Exception <class 'gdb.MemoryError'> Cannot access memory at address 0x5:
#0  0xb774dcb0 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x5
(gdb) thread 3
[Switching to thread 3 (Thread 0xb6becb40 (LWP 18937))]
#0  0xb774dcb0 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb774dcb0 in ?? ()
#1  0x000d6ee6 in ?? ()

ninja@vm:build$ cat /proc/`pidof loader.elf`/maps | grep b774d
b774b000-b774d000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]
b774d000-b774f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
```

So it looks like all threads are inside a system call? That's likely since I'm expecting them all to be stuck on `ptread_mutex_lock`, but why don't I have valid stack frames below that? Why the `0x5` address for thread 2? And why does thread 3 have `0xd6ee6` on the stack, which isn't even mentioned in the memory map?